# Контролирование работы ffmpeg из PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, rtsp

Из php с помощью exec() вызывается ffmpeg, который кладёт в контейнер RTSP поток, т.е. теоретически, ffmpeg может выполняться бесконечно долго, в может спустя секунду прерваться.

Сам процесс, который зависает на exec() - форк, которого создал главный процесс демона. (Если что, он забирает параметры потока от главного через ZeroMQ)

**Вопрос:** как главному процессу можно достоверно (не по косвенным признакам) знать, что происходит с ffmpeg? В идеале текущий статус записи (при запуске ffmpeg в консоли - последняя строчка выхлопа), или хотя бы знать причину завершения процесса ffmpeg.

P.S. Я вижу только вариант с парсингом выхлопа ffmpeg (лог-файл), но вариант не самый радужный.

Comment: дочерний процесс может ровно так же выводить данные в stdout, которые будет забирать родительский процесс. посмотрите [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.passthru.php) и [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php).